# Cant pattern match Map[String, Any] in scala

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching

Im trying to stringify this Map to a json string:

```
val value = Map(
        "items" -> Seq(
            Map(
                "type" -> Seq("http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"),
                "properties" -> Map(
                    "brand" -> Seq("Bridgestone"),
                    "category" -> Seq("Truck Tires"),
                    "name" -> Seq("R-195F"),
                    "photo" -> Seq(""),
                    "price" -> Seq("$300.09"),
                    "url" -> Seq("http://www.bridgestonetrucktires.com")
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

with this method:

```
    def beautify(map: Map[String, Any]): String = {
    val keys = map.keys.toSeq
    keys.map(key => {
        val value: Any = map.get(key).get
        value match {
            case x: Map[String, Any] => "\"" + key + "\": " + beautify(x)
            case x: Seq[String] => "\"" + key + "\": " + x.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
            case x: Seq[Map[String, Any]] => x.map(el => beautify(el)).mkString("[", ", ", "]")
        }
    }).mkString("{", ", ", "}")
}
```

The problem is that when I get the key "items", and try to match the value inside here:

```
value match {
            case x: Map[String, Any] => "\"" + key + "\": " + beautify(x)
            case x: Seq[String] => "\"" + key + "\": " + x.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
            case x: Seq[Map[String, Any]] => x.map(el => beautify(el)).mkString("[", ", ", "]")
        }
```

It's matching with this line:

```
case x: Seq[String] => "\"" + key + "\": " + x.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
```

and not with this one:

```
case x: Seq[Map[String, Any]] => x.map(el => beautify(el)).mkString("[", ", ", "]")
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case x: Seq[Map[String, Any]]` is unreachable because it has the same runtime type as `case x: Seq[String]`. The type arguments within `Seq` are eliminated by erasure when you build your program.

There are a couple ways around this - I'll give you the simplest. First, wrap the class in case classes:

```
case class SeqMap(value: Seq[Map[String, Any]])
```

Then your value will look like:

```
val value = Map(
  "items" -> SeqMap(
    Seq(Map(
      "type" -> Seq("http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"),
      "properties" -> Map(
        "brand" -> Seq("Bridgestone"),
        "category" -> Seq("Truck Tires"),
        "name" -> Seq("R-195F"),
        "photo" -> Seq(""),
        "price" -> Seq("$300.09"),
        "url" -> Seq("http://www.bridgestonetrucktires.com")
      )
    ))
  )
)
```

And, your new match statement:

```
case x: Map[String, Any] => ...
case x: Seq[String] => ...
case x: SeqMap => ...
```

And, even still, the `String` in `Map[String, Any]` and `Seq[String]` any are ignored due to type erasure. As an example, the runtime types of `Seq[String]` and `Seq[Int]` are the same.

There are more ways to overcome type erasure in Scala - the above is example is the quickest and simplest to get you on your way.